# Questions about the notifications API

Tags: desire2learn

We have a need to fetch notifications for a particular user.  By notifications, I mean the "Alert" items that appear in the D2L minibar (Message alerts, Update alerts, Subscription alerts).

We want to integrate some of these items into our CMS' menu.

I see that D2L offers a Notifications API:
http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#id1

**Question 1:** Is the notifications API flexible enough to grab the items described above for a user?

**Question 2:**

To experiment with the notifications API, I tried using the following API call:
http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-notifications-instant-carriers-

And a 403 error was encountered.

The documentation states:

> These routes depend upon the back-end service having the Notifications tool active. If the service does not have the Notifications tool active, then all calls to these routes will result in authorization (403) error results.

Where is the option in the backend to toggle this setting?  Is this setting available in DOME somewhere?

**Question 3:** For the Alert items, is there a static link to view these items on D2L?

For example, I am able to access the:

- Pager - at
  example.desire2learn.com/d2l/lms/pager/messageList.d2l?ou=ORGID
- Email - at example.desire2learn.com/d2l/lms/email/frame.d2l?ou=ORGID

But, there doesn't appear to be a way to access the "Update Alerts" and "Subscription Alerts" items from a static link.  They only appear via AJAX when you click on these icons in the minibar.  If I am overlooking where these links are, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your questions, Ray. I'm taking steps to prepare answers for them, but it may take some time.

Comment: Appreciate your posts on Stackoverflow, Viktor.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be long-ish, and probably isn't what you want to hear. First off, there is a strong distinction between "alerts" (the items that show up in the minibar) and "notifications". The Notifications API is simply exposing the "Instant Notifications preference" table that you can see when you open your user's `Notifications` settings page (the page at url: http://yourLMS.edu/d2l/Notifications/Settings).

The types of messages that can be sent as a "notification" are the rows in the Instant Notifications table; the "carriers", or endpoints, for them are the columns of checkboxes. The Notifications API exposes this table, letting you retrieve it's current state, and change the setting for a checkbox at the vertex of a notification `messageTypeId` and a `carrierId`.

So, to answer your specific questions:

**Question 1**. No, the Notifications API does not currently provide any access to the alerts that appear in the minibar control in the LMS' web UI.

**Question 2**. Your 403 may indicate that your calling user context does not have the permission required to use the Notifications tool: the calling user must have a role that grants them the ability to `Receive Instant Notifications` -- without that, the API call to retrieve the carriers list results in a 403.

If your org has had the Notifications tool turned off entirely, then it's likely no user will be able to see their Notifications setting page through the Web UI, and to turn it back on may require your organization to call D2L's support desk to have it turned back on: I'm not sure that client organization admins have the ability to select what tools are on and which are off without intervention from the support desk.

**Question 3**. I do not believe there is a static page for the Update and Subscription alert lists.